# Does Jdbc in Google App Scripts (in Google Sheets) support named instances in MS SQL Server?

Tags: google-apps-script, jdbc, google-sheets

**Does anyone know how to get named instances to work, or, are they even supported?**

The following **doesn't work**, it produces:
Exception: Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password.

```
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://myserver.com\\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=MyDatabase;","MyUser","MyPassword")
```

The following **works** (given that 61570 is the port assigned to the instance SQLEXPRESS):

```
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://myserver.com:61570;databaseName=MyDatabase;","MyUser","MyPassword")
```

As far as I am aware, when you specify a named instance, there is some hand-shaking behind the scenes that normally happens:

1. Contact the server and get the port for the named instance.
2. Establish a connection with the returned port.

Comment: I don't believe you can. If you look up the official [JDBC documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html) (Apps Script's JDBC service is just a wrapper), it looks like you have to explicitly define the port  number, otherwise it defaults to port number 3306.

Comment: For the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver in general, for named instances to work you need to have the SQL Server Browser service running (and it needs to be remote accessible). Not sure if that is different or not for Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Apps Script wrapper for **Jdbc** does not include a method for connecting to named instances.  You do have to specify a port to connect to when requesting a connection.

---

#### References:

- Apps Script [Class Jdbc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc#getConnection(String))